# how to solve "[Error 5] Access is denied " during adding data to windows registry in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pycharm, winreg

this is my code:

```
import _winreg
import sys

try:
    key = _winreg.OpenKey(_winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, 'Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run',
                          _winreg.KEY_SET_VALUE)
    _winreg.SetValueEx(key, 'pytest', 0, _winreg.REG_BINARY, 'C:\Users\Default\Desktop\est.py')
    _winreg.QueryInfoKey(key)
    key.Close()
    print "Successfully Added"
except:
    print "Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[1],sys.exc_info()[0]
```

i have made an exe out of this by doing

```
pyinstaller.exe --onefile testDemo.py
```

it produces a "**testDemo.exe**" file.
when i try to run it in cmd[with or without administrator mode]  i get this.

```
Unexpected error: [Error 5] Access is denied <type 'exceptions.WindowsError'>
```

how to solve it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 3rd parameter **reserved** is missed in the call of OpenKey.

> winreg.OpenKeyEx(key, sub_key, reserved=0, access=KEY_READ)

**reserved** is a reserved integer, and must be zero. The default is zero.